# В разметку автоматически добавляется атрибут vk_xxxxx=“subscribed”

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jquery-ui

При отладке обнаружил, что в разметку виджета [Spinner jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/) автоматически добавляется атрибут `vk_xxxxx=“subscribed”`, где `xxxxx` – пятиразрядное шестнадцатеричное число (число меняется при каждом обновлении отладки). Происходит это только, когда отладка выполняется в браузере Chrome. В других браузерах этого атрибута в разметке не видно.
Переустановка хрома не помогла. Все расширения в хроме отключены.
Думаю, что это попытка незаметно навязать пользователю какую-то подписку `Вконтакте`.
Что это может быть? Как этот атрибут попадает в разметку?

Comment: На нескольких сайтах видел версию, что так работает защита Касперского. У вас стоит что-нибудь подобное?

Comment: Да, стоит Касперский. Сейчас проверю, исчезнет ли это явление при отключении Касперского.  
Если это действительно Касперский делает, то интересно, в чем состоит механизм такой защиты?

Comment: Что показала проверка?

Answer (score 1):

http://gbx.ru/index.php?s=db8c3f6d78f10ce459dcf531788e2163&showtopic=109628&pid=2170962&st=0&#entry2170962
говорят, касперский ставит метку, почему vk - непонятно. если отключить все файерволы и антивири?